# Image dimensions dont work

Tags: html, css

so basically I'm trying to put an image under some text, but I want to resize the image. 
I downloaded it as a 256x256 pixel image, I want it to be a 32x32 pixel image.

```
div {
height: 1px;
width: 1px;
```

}

is my CSS

The div just has an image src in it that puts the image on page, that works fine.

Comment: Can you post more code, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image resized you need to resize the image it self not the div. 
You can either do:

```
<style>
#myimg {
    width 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Note on this second one it will target every div and image in the page. I recommend using an ID or Class to call the image

or:

```
<style>
div img {
    width 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
</style>
```

I just grabbed google logo for test

```
<div id="mydiv"><img id="myimg" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" /></div>
```